# Tilt to Live High Score Anomaly

Tags: tilt-to-live

Looking at the high scores for Tilt to Live, there are an awful lot of high scores near 2,147,500,000. Is there something that happens when you approach that score?

Answer (score 1):

Near 2,147,500 you say? Would *near* happen to be precisely 2,147,483?

Because that sounds like it would be [MaxInt](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-CA/library/296az74e.aspx). The maximum value of a 32-bit signed integer.

Unless global leaderboards are protected, or cleaned regularly, they inevitably get filled by hackers/cheaters submitting scores they manually entered and never actually achieved. This is how for race leaderboards you often see times of 1 second or under.

What happens if you managed to achieve that score and went over? Depends on how the game was programmed. The app could crash, the score could reset to 0, the score could flip and be ***negative*** 2,147,483...

Comment: This could do with some clarification - from experience (and from the page you linked) MaxInt for a 32 bit number is 2147483647 - 1000 times higher than the number in question here... The logic could be sound still but the wording as it stands is very confusing.

Comment: `divided by 1000 for 3 decimal places` Whoops, meant 2,147,500,**000**. But what’s puzzling is that there are scores that are slightly higher than 2^31, as well as a few scores that are much higher. Though cheating *is* a good explanation.